# IBM Domino Designer

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm newbie in Domino Designer and want to preview xpage and views in web browser but the following message has appear

```
    To successfully previw this document in a web browser,please add(or modify)
    the ACL anonmyous(or the default ACL) to have at least author access
    with the ability to create document.
```

Can any oe help me please?

Comment: If you have the possibility then install a Domino server on your local development computer and test with this server. The local preview is restricted and not really a good way to test and debug XPages applications.

Comment: I see that the correct answer has been given, however I want to point out that understanding ACLs is one of the fundamental skills required for any useful Notes/Domino/xpages development. I think that before you go any farther, you probably should find some good tutorials on the basics. Here's an old, but still ver useful one about ACLs: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Using_the_ACL/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to modify the ACL (Access Control List) in the Database Properties

1. From the top menu in the Notes or Designer client click File/Application/Access Control
2. Click Add button then type **Anonymous**
3. Give Anonymous Author Access with Create Documents checked off.

Answer (score 3):

Eric is correct.

To learn about the fundamentals of Domino as application server you might want to read my [introduction series](http://notessensei.com/blog/2013/12/domino-development-back-to-basics-overview.html). It covers:

- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Overview
- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Part 1: The NSF
- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Part 2: Forms and Documents
- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Part 3: Not all Documents are created equally
- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Part 4: Domino views are different
- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Part 5: Finding data - Collections and Search
- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Part 6: Better save than sorry - Security
- Domino Development - Back to Basics - Part 7: Map Reduce Domino Style

That should give you a good head start